# Single Sign on to site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, curl, single-sign-on

I am needing help with single sign on. I have siteA.com that requires login credentials, once you are in SiteA.com you can do many things and one of them is access another application siteB.com. If you click on the option to go to this other application, the other application also has a login screen whose credentials are the **same** as siteA.com, so siteA.com and siteB.com have login screens of their own with the same credentials.

I am trying to make it a single sign on is there anyway I can remote login or pass credentials from siteA.com to siteB.com?

I am interested in:
Solved exactly same problem (actually also for 4 domains). The only solution I've came up with was, to include 3 hidden iframes on the 'Successful login page' and those iframes just load www.domain1.com/register_session.php, www.domain2.com/register_session.php, etc....

As a parameter for register_session.php I use 'sid' which contains session ID:

```
session_id($_GET['sid']);
session_start();
```

This is actually for keeping session alive on all those domains but the same would be for your case with cookies.

I think this could work but the problem is given the credentials, how can I make the script login to siteB.com?

I have done something which KIND of works...I copied the html of siteB.com and added that to hidden in siteA.com and at siteA.com made it do a double POST, one to siteA.com's login and another to siteB.com's login. This works only if the user has logged in to siteB.com lately, I think that logging in to siteB.com it sets a cookie to control access thats why doing the double POST allows you to fool the login system and as long as the correct credentials are provided it does a successful grab of login cookie, allowing you to login.

Comment: Have you looked into OpenID or do you strictly want to roll your own?

Comment: I want my own prefrable php, note the purpose is to allow ALL users that login to siteA.com to be able to access siteB.com without reentering their credentials. OpenID seems like you must link up your accounts that are affiliated to your credentials. I wouldnt ask my users to sign up for OpenID so I want to make my own.

Comment: Yes, something like OpenID (which is what I use for this site, actually) is great for applications that are inherently social and/or geared towards people who spend a great deal of time online and in various online services (ie. people who either already have an OpenID or have heard of it and are comfortable with it). But if this doesn't sound like your user base, rolling your own will probably suit you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the user's information in a cookie( such as the user's id in the database ) then on the login page, look for that cookie. if it exists and is a valid user, go ahead and log them in.

When creating a cookie, you should be able to set it's domain to the domain of siteB.com so that siteB.com can see it. Simply create one cookie for each domain that needs to be able to read that cookie, and set acceptable expires settings on each cookie so that they either expire on session end or after x days.

Depending on how much security you need, you may need to put some kind of protection to prevent someone from simply creating their own cookie to get in freely (such as encryption)

Comment: i cant perform the login for siteB.com, I cant tinker even with the login setup of siteB.com, I have to somehow remotely provide to siteB.com the credentials and login

Comment: how does siteB.com do it's login? form POST/GET? ajax request? more than likely if you don't have direct access to the back-end of siteB.com  you won't be able to pull it off.

Comment: It sounds almost like you are trying to create a site that looks like another site so that people can use it to login so that you can steal their credentials.

Comment: hahaha no, I am working in a corporate environment and the siteB is the infrastructure team's application and siteA.com is my application. The logins are LDAP so its 1 login for all so thats why I am trying to SSO so users in my app dont need to enter login again.

Comment: Understood. You are going to need to know how the siteB.com authentication and session works if you are going to get your authentication from siteA.com to carry over to siteB.com. More than likely it uses session variables, so you will just have to find a way to either mimick or pass along the session variables.

Comment: read my post above I updated. I mimicked it and that works mostly. The problem now is that if the session from siteB.com is destroyed, my siteA.com doesnt have permission to create that login session to siteB.com, it says something about syncing, basically implying that it detects the different POST locations at session creation but not at sessino fetching.

Answer (score 0):

I once had to tackle a similar problem.  What I ended up doing was appending a hash to the URL query string of any link [or form] going from SiteA to SiteB, and visa versa.  I used an MD5 hash of the user ID in the database for the value.  On both sites, if that hash is present in $_GET, log the user in using a search for "MD5(user_id) = ?" instead of searching by username and password.

Edit:  Note, this isn't a very secure solution - it just happened to be perfect for what I was trying to achieve.  Please do keep security in mind.  In my post above, an attacker could potentially determine that the token is an MD5 hash of an integer and start tinkering with it.